# Anime where a boy enrolls in a magic school not knowing it's about magic, winds up with a bunch of girls involved with him

Tags: story-identification, anime

The main character is blond with glasses. He goes to this high school because it is easy to get in. What he does not know is that it is a high school for people with magic. Anyways he bumps into two women arguing and he intervenes. Well he ends up seeing one of their panties. So at the opening ceremony that girl challenges him to a duel. He childhood friend, who happens to go there too but is in a higher grade, tries to prevent the fight. The two end up fighting anyways and he loses. He can use magic but he doesn't know it because when he does he can't remember what happens. A tiny girl and a huge guy end up dueling. He tries to stop the fight but in the middle of it he uses his magic without knowing and ends the fight. When he uses his magic a blue symbol appears on the top left of his chest. Another girls notices the symbol and says he is her enemy.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like the setup for *[Maken-Ki!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maken-ki!)*

> Takeru Ohyama has enrolled at Tenbi Academy, a private prep high school that converted from all-girls to co-ed. Hoping to have a life full of ogling pretty girls, he reunites with childhood friend Haruko Amaya, who shows him around school. However, he learns that the school is for students who possess magical and spiritual energies called Elements and who wield crafted weapons known as Makens. The students engage in school sanctioned combat matches that showcase their powers. While his own ability and Maken is not apparent at first, Takeru soon finds himself surrounded by girls, including Inaho Kushiya, an attractive girl who says she's his fiancée, and Kodama Himegami, a popular blonde who says she wants to kill him. He joins the Security Committee (魔導検警機構, madō kenkei kikō, lit. "anti-evil organization"), also known as Maken-ki, which supports the student council's operations.

Indeed, his early encounter with Kodama as she watches a duel between two girls features panties, an accidental kids, and her proclaiming him her "mortal enemy" as he runs off.

### Trailer

As might be guessed by the thumbnail image, there is a lot of fanservice.

Found with a search for `anime magic school panties duel`

Comment: Yes that is the anime thank you so much. It has been stuck in my head for weeks now.

Comment: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]